# file's owner of xib is not what i expect

Tags: interface-builder

i'm using xcode4.
i have a xib window (perhaps copyed by another one, i forgot because i have made it some times ago) named: chooseCharacter.xib
i have the chooseCharacter.h and .m as view controller (i thought)
i have added

```
-(IBAction)doneButtonClick;
```

on the chooseCharacter.h but i've not seen it in interface builder actions...
i have added this on HighScoreViewController.h and it now shows up...
however, if i put it on HighScoreViewController.h i must put the implementation in chooseCharacter.m or i get

```
-[ChooseCharacter doneButtonClick]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcc0d9b0'
```

seems that the window is binded with a file's owner that is HighScoreViewController.h but search implementation in ChooseCharacter.m!!!

how can i bind the xib to the right file?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it.
selecting in interface builder, file's owner and clicking in identity inspector under class was HighScoreViewController, changed to chooseCharacter now it works